# Intercept deserialization errors in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, deserialization, soapfault

I was recently asked by a security team if it was possible to change the message returned from deserialization issues within a WCF service. The error in question was when they intercepted the message and passed an integer that was outside the bounds of Int32.

> The value '2147483649' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.

My answer was that the deserialization process occurs before a single line of my service is executed and that it is not possible. However, is it possible to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have [includeExceptionDetailInFaults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.includeexceptiondetailinfaults%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)="true". True is the default value that should be set to false before you do a production deploy. Once this is false you will get a generic error message. That should be enough to make security happy.

An even better option is to implement an [IErrorHandler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/07/wcf-extensibility-ierrorhandler.aspx). That's the extension point that allow you to handle the exception, even though it happens before execution reaches your service code.